# count array object with condition in mongodb and spring-boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, rest, backend

I want to count the number of videos in each ***mediaList*** and then return the total number of videos in the document.

```
    {
    _id: ObjectId("5f9d8d02d7bb2c56b678614c"),
    mainTopicId: "5f8066dad0b65b3b9ca67e4b",
    subTopicId: "5f9d89f5d7bb2c56b678614b",
    userIdLiked: [
        "5fe4560f19050e372a2a17f8",
        "5f8061e0d0b65b3b9ca67e49"
    ],
    likeCount: NumberInt(2),
    mediaList: [
        {
            url: "ad491eb8-7f28-47da-9d35-fe83bb4f8eb0.mp4",
            mediaType: "VIDEO"
        }
    ],
    text: "this sample text",
    title: "sample title",
    created: ISODate("2020-10-31T16:12:50.615Z"),
    updated: ISODate("2020-10-31T16:12:50.615Z"),
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("5f9d8f95d7bb2c56b678614e"),
    mainTopicId: "5f8066dad0b65b3b9ca67e4b",
    subTopicId: "5f67816fb2ae8c3e1f203946",
    userIdLiked: [
        "5f8061e0d0b65b3b9ca67e49"
    ],
    mediaList: [
        {
            url: "5633c4b2-d3aa-4d7c-8419-1403e43674b1.mp4",
            mediaType: "VIDEO"
        }
    ],
    text: "sample text 2",
    title: "sample title 2",
    created: ISODate("2020-10-31T16:23:49.488Z"),
    updated: ISODate("2020-10-31T16:23:49.488Z"),
    _class: "com.example.api.pregnancy.models.Content"
}
```

I use this Spring-boot code for sum `likeCount` in document.
now i want count total ***mediaType*** when  is ***VIDEO*** type

```
 Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                project("subTopicId").and("likeCount").as("sumLikeCount"),
                group("subTopicId").sum("sumLikeCount").as("totalCount")
        );
```

Comment: Does the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        
      p-> new Document("$project",
                new Document("totalVideos",
                    new Document("$size",
                        new Document("$filter",
                            new Document("input","$mediaList").append("cond",
                                new Document("$eq",Arrays.asList("$$this.mediaType","VIDEO"))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )

    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());
```

Spring-data doesn't provide few operation like `$addFields`, `$filter`. So what we can do is to go with a [trick using BSON](http://pingax.com/trick-convert-mongo-shell-query-equivalent-java-objects/)

Note : This code is not tested, Hope, it would work. It was written based on **working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MLq2HvWt-KP)**